# Apache CXF JAXB Marshaller not marshalling @XmlAttribute correctly

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cxf, xml-attribute

I am trying to get an XML response from my CXF version 3.1 based REST service in java in the following format.

```
<root>
 <element a="X" b="1.2" c="3.2"/>
 <element a="Y" b="5.5" c="1.4"/>
 <element a="Z" b="54.2" c="55.4"/>
</root>
```

I have defined my DTO as below :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class Root{

    private List<Element> element;

    ---getters setters and no arg constructor--
}
```

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {
    "a","b","c"})
@XmlRootElement(name="element")
public class Element{

    @XmlAttribute
    private String a;

    @XmlAttribute
    private Double b;

    @XmlAttribute
    private Double c;

    ---Getter Setter---

}
```

I have not overriden any mapper, so default CXF JAXB xml mapper is in action.

But my xml response is coming as :-

```
<root>
   <element>
      <element>
          <a>X</a>
          <b>1.2</b>
          <c>3.2</c>
       </element>
       <element>
          <a>Y</a>
          <b>5.5</b>
          <c>1.4</c>
       </element>
       <element>
          <a>Z</a>
          <b>54.2</b>
          <c>55.4</c>
       </element>
    </element>
</root>
```

I have checked the Moxy API option as well, but that i cant use. Can someone please help that what is wrong with my code or what is missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @bdoughan, any suggestions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite some time, i found the problem and then figurred out the solution as well.

**Problem**

The problem was that apache cxf by default marshaller i.e. JAXB was not honouring the attribute annotations and hence was represnting the fields as elements instead of attributes.

**Solution**

Since by default serialization and de-serialization mechanism i.e. JAXB was not working hence we need to override this. 
And here my problem got solved by using Jackson as the serialization and de-serialization api.

Jackson starting with 2.0 verison provide both JSON as well as XML formats, and have exposed xml specific annotations for the same.

Use @JacksonXmlProperty with attribute set as true and then overriding the ObjectMapper bean as below solved the problem.

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
        //overriding apache cxf JAXB mapper to use jackson mapper.
        AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
        objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        return objectMapper;
```